# Обход листа с словарями и вычисление связей по ключу

Tags: python-3.x, list, словари

Есть вопрос к сообществу.

Есть некая база DB в ней есть таблица аккаунтов вида:

```
account_id | parent_id
------------------------
5555       | None (пустой)
```

Если parent_id = пустой , то это родитель для других аккаунтов.

Если parent_id содержит integer число то это account_id родителя, например

```
account_id | parent_id
-----------------------
6666       | 5555
```

Мне нужно посчитать кол-во переходов по родительству от parent_id = None
до последнего потомка или наоборот.

Получился такой код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

sql = "select * from accounts"


try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='DB' user='postgres'" \
                            " host='postgres.contora.com' password='xxxxxxxx'")
except psycopg2.Error as err:
    print("Connection error: {}".format(err))

try:
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    cur.execute(sql)
    data = cur.fetchall()
except psycopg2.Error as err:
    print("Query error: {}".format(err))

data_dict = []
for row in data:
    data_dict.append(dict(row))


start_count = 0

for data_dict[start_count] in data_dict:
    ib_level = 0
    if data_dict[start_count].get('parent_id') is None:
        data_dict[start_count].update({'IB_level': ib_level})
        print('IB level 0:\n')
        print(data_dict[start_count])
    elif isinstance(data_dict[start_count].get('parent_id'), int):
        ib_level_calc = ib_level + 1
        data_dict[start_count].update({'IB_level': ib_level_calc})
        print('IB level 1:\n')
        print(data_dict[start_count])
    start_count = start_count + 1
```

В коде я беру данные из базы, преобразую в список словарей вида (account_id, parent_id), для каждого словаря в списке сравниваю с критерием родительства и добавляю новый итем IB_level с значением перехода (0 родитель, 1 потомок, 2 потомок потомка) к проверенному словарю.

Удается посчитать переход только от 0 к 1 т.е. только 1 отношение. Проблема в том, что кол-во переходов неизвестно, а требуется внести все степени отношений, т.е. насколько далеко каждый аккаунт находится от своего родителя с parent_id = None, выражаемое числом IB_level.

Заранее спасибо за любую информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел как это сделать.

```
# Prereq.
# sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
# sudo pip3 install psycopg2

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
sql = "select * from accounts"


try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db' user='user'" \
                            " host='ps.contora.com' password='xxxxxxx'")
except psycopg2.Error as err:
    print("Connection error: {}".format(err))

try:
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    cur.execute(sql)
    data = cur.fetchall()
except psycopg2.Error as err:
    print("Query error: {}".format(err))


class Account:
    def __init__(self, i, p, id_m, ac_n, mt4_g):
        self.account_id = i
        self.parent_id = p
        self.ib_number = id_m
        self.account_number = ac_n
        self.mt4_group = mt4_g

data_dict = []
for row in data:
    data_dict.append(Account(row.get('account_id'),
                             row.get('parent_id'),
                             row.get('ib_number'),
                             row.get('account_number'),
                             row.get('mt4_group')
                             ))

cLvlAccs = [None]
cLvl = 0
while len(cLvlAccs) > 0:
    newLvlAccs = []
    for acc in data_dict:
        if (cLvlAccs.count(acc.parent_id) > 0):
            acc.lvl = cLvl
            newLvlAccs.append(acc.account_id)
    cLvlAccs = newLvlAccs
    cLvl += 1

for acc in data_dict:
    print("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}".format(acc.account_id,
                                           acc.parent_id,
                                           acc.lvl,
                                           acc.ib_number,
                                           acc.account_number,
                                           acc.mt4_group
                                           ))
```